# Input metafield into css - after > content: "metafield"

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I have an ::after element in a shopify page and instead of string content, I would like to use a metafield. CSS are written in liquid file (Online store > Edit code). I created a metafield {{ shop.metafields.judgeme.verified_reviews.value }} but it doesnt work.

So instead of this:
`.jdgm-all-reviews-page__title::after { content: "Verified Reviews"; }`

I used this:

`.jdgm-all-reviews-page__title::after { content: {{ shop.metafields.judgeme.verified_reviews.value }}; }` 
I also tried to add this piece of code to the beginning of the liquid file {% assign verified_reviews = shop.metafields.judgeme.verified_reviews.value %} and  content: {{ verified_review }}; but that doesnt works too. Do you have any idea what could work or if it's even possible? Thank you for any advice.

So instead of this:
`.jdgm-all-reviews-page__title::after { content: "Verified Reviews"; }`

I used this:

`.jdgm-all-reviews-page__title::after { content: {{ shop.metafields.judgeme.verified_reviews.value }}; }`

Comment: Make sure you name your css file foo.css.liquid to ensure that liquid gets translated by Shopify!